# Separate the main and the class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

i start to learn Objective-C and write class but my problem is that my class not recognize by the main

this is my main:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        Fraction *fraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

my interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject

-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) n;
-(int) numerator;
-(int) denomerator;
-(double) convertToNum;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denomerator;
}

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denomerator);
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) n
{
    denomerator = n;
}

-(int) numerator
{
    return  numerator;
}

-(int) denomerator
{
    return denomerator;
}

-(double) convertToNum
{
    if (denomerator != 0)
    {
        return (double) numerator / denomerator;
    }
    else
    {
        return NAN;
    }
}

@end
```

when i wrote `Fraction *fraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];` my error message is **use of undeclared identifier Fraction**

Comment: did you import Fraction.h in main.m ? If not do it #import "Fraction.h"

Comment: Again the same problem Fraction Class... some Training class on ios, has only this problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main.m, you need to add

```
#import "Fraction.h"
```

so that the compiler knows about Fractions.